# Extract Json in Presto

Tags: json, extract, presto

I have got below data in some complex format of json, which is neither a pure json not array.

[image]

I have tried to pull the specific values by using below queries that did not work

```
SELECT json_array_extract_scalar(bankdetails, '$.bank') FROM ade.evangelist_oao.oaocustomfundingupdateaoapplicationsvc ;
```

> Query failed (#20200717_121411_01261_cav8k): line 1:8: Unexpected
> parameters (row(bank varchar), varchar(6)) for function
> json_extract_scalar. Expected: json_extract_scalar(varchar(x),
> JsonPath) , json_extract_scalar(json, JsonPath) [DB Errorcode=1]

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(accounts, '$.fundingsrcs.method') FROM ade.evangelist_oao.oaocustomfundingupdateaoapplicationsvc ;
```

> Query failed (#20200717_121600_01270_cav8k): line 1:8: Unexpected
> parameters (array(row(fundingsrcs array(row(method varchar,amount
> bigint)))), varchar(20)) for function json_extract_scalar. Expected:
> json_extract_scalar(varchar(x), JsonPath) , json_extract_scalar(json,
> JsonPath) [DB Errorcode=1]

How can i get the **b840** value of bankdetails field and **CUSTOMFUNDING** value of accounts field in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual type is ROW (not JSON), so you can retrieve the value with

```sql
SELECT bankdetails.bank FROM ...
```

Comment: for bankdetails your solution worked but when i run the below command  SELECT accounts.fundingsrcs.method from ade.evangelist_oao.oaocustomfundingupdateaoapplicationsvc ;  then i got error Expression accounts is not of type ROW [DB Errorcode=1]

Comment: The root type of accounts column is ARRAY, so please try SELECT accounts[0]...